# SignalR: webSockets timed out when trying to connect. Possible CORS issue

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr, cors

I am trying to write a mobile app (angular) that connects to an existing website that has a signalr hub. I have signalr configured on the web server:

```
 // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                     EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

The server is running on site: http://localhost:62115/

I have another client application running on http://localhost:4434/ and I am trying to consume the signalr hub from http://localhost:62115/:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:62115/signalr/hubs";

        var queueProxy = $.connection.queueHub;

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                alert('yes');
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
```

But signalr will not connect. I get the error **No transport could be initialized successfully**. Below is my log:

```
[16:19:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:19:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: No hubs have been subscribed to.  The client will not receive data from hubs.  To fix, declare at least one client side function prior to connection start for each hub you wish to subscribe to.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:19:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://localhost:62115/signalr/hubs/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%5D'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:19:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:62115/signalr/hubs/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=yNATl6%2FEQt710oI6ZGOV9%2F61Ry2SRjKQOgPDxKuXGSCYagKpbQKY5DOzRWdk1ggv6XaIm%2FJ2TUkkbmEkgCJyKHAKwy3ZweftP%2FYzRglLGe492Z4RDYY%2Btj8Aah3IhHIo&connectionData=%5B%5D&tid=2'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:19:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets timed out when trying to connect.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:62115/signalr/hubs/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clie…AKwy3ZweftP%2FYzRglLGe492Z4RDYY%2Btj8Aah3IhHIo&connectionData=%5B%5D&tid=5'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents timed out when trying to connect.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:62115/signalr/hubs/connect?transport=longPolling&clientPro…AKwy3ZweftP%2FYzRglLGe492Z4RDYY%2Btj8Aah3IhHIo&connectionData=%5B%5D&tid=6'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:14 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling timed out when trying to connect.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:14 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Aborted xhr request.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81 [16:20:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and wanted to document the solution here in case anyone else is pulling their hair out over a SignalR connection issue. There are two separate oddball reasons for failure:

**Clock Synchronization Issue**.
I am publishing to Azure, and SignalR worked PERFECTLY on the staging and production environment. It suddenly would no longer connect in my dev environment.

I had recently set my system clock back one hour over what it should be within the same time zone. When I corrected the date and time, SignalR started working perfectly for all protocols on my local machine. I can't find documentation of this anywhere, but I do know that Azure Tables, Queues, and Blobs require a synchronized clock within 15 minutes.

**Azure SignalR Backplane Service Bus Issue**.
I am using an Azure Service Bus Backplane to synch messaging across multiple web front end instances. I actually had a service bus corrupt (I have no idea why and have asked this question in a separate post). I know it's the service bus because when I commented out the GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus method call in my OWIN startup, things worked perfectly. When I switched my connection string to a different service bus, it worked perfectly. But ONE BUS causes intermittent failure.

Comment: I don't understand why clock would be an issue for SignalR. Was the Dev environment in your scenario the client machine, or the server? Is the issue that SignalR was tightly coupled to a Queue which was in a different timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues, and for some time it was an uphill battle when I upgrated my nuget packages to the latest versions regarding cross domain. Could you try the following and let me know if this resolved your issues?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = true });
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // your client localhost
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:4434", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
    }
}
```

---

```
// wack "/hubs"
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:62115/signalr/

$.connection.hub.start({ xdomain: true })
    .done(function () { 
        console.log('Connected. connectionId : ' + $.connection.hub.id); })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('Could not connect!');
});
```

---

And finally be sure to reference the script in the `<head>` of your client side app. Notice you are explicitly referencing the localhost your server is running.

```
<script src="//localhost:62115/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - that answer did it for me. I adapted it my scenario but enabling CORS was the solution, which wasn't evident from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  The negotiation step would list out all the transport methods, but then 1 by 1 they would timeout (after 5 seconds for me).  Even long polling was broken.

In my case, we use Redis as a cache for SignalR.  My local copy worked fine since we have a conditional that only uses the Redis cache for prod.  So I figured it was something with that.

**Updating all the related packages fixed the issue for me:**

- All of the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR packages, including the client-side lib
- All of the Microsoft.Owin packages
- StackExchange.Redis
- All of the Autofac packages (since AutoFac handled the Redis dependency being injected)